# How to fix Charset mismatch between Nifi cluster and Custom Processor

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have build a custom processor which process JSON input , do some formating and calculations , add all values as attributes and transfer the flowFile

The Problem is one of these values having Arabic characters, and the attribute which should have this value is empty or having question Marks

note: the same custom processor is running without issues on local nifi (PC) and all values are processed well , this only happened when using this processor in different nifi cluster

update:
--- Nifi FLow

InvokeHttp (some API) -> splitJson -> customProcessor -> putSQL

--

-- the response of InvokeHttp is Json , some of its values are english and some are Arabic

-- Parsing the Json in custom Processor using jsonPath Java Library 
-- Each result is stored in flowFile attribute,

The issue is the attributes are not showing values in Arabic, it shows empty value

Comment: could you provide the property descriptors that cause you the problem and how you built them? It's hard telling the issue only based on what you are telling us..

Comment: also, how do you read them

Comment: seems the problem in your custom processor. please provide the code. especially the parts where you are reading flowfile stream and parsing json, and writing...

Comment: My guess is that one of the processors uses the "system" standard encoding while others are using an explicit UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding. As the other commenters have said, please share the code of your custom processor. Is there a reason you need custom logic rather than just `EvaluateJsonPath` to extract JSON values from the content to flowfile attributes?